# Problem to get an item from an AngularFireList

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not able to get an object when I try to look for it through one of its attributes in an AngularFireList. What do you suggest?

[Firebase Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqCs9.png)

***SERVICE***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Prestamo } from '../models/prestamo';
import { FirebaseDatabase } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrestamoService {

  prestamoLista: AngularFireList<any>;
  prestamoSeleccionado: Prestamo = new Prestamo();

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}



  obtenerPrestamo(codigo: string)
  {
    return this.prestamoLista = this.firebase.list('prestamos', ref => ref.orderByChild('codigo').equalTo(codigo));
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you assign `this.prestamoLista`, but what do you try to do with the result? Looks like this might be helpful https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using valueChanges to fix this use:

```
.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(items => {
    return items.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.val();
      const key = a.payload.key;
      return {key, ..data};   
    });
```

Then you can subscribe to this.